# best approach for small network cut off from main domain

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, ip, domain-name-system

I'm not an IT guy so please bear with me, any helpful approaches for this would be great.

My team and I are working in a field project that essentially made us physically move to a new location, making us  lose access to the intranet domain.

Our setup right now is more less like this:

- A simple linksys router where all computers connect (about 7, including one Windows Server 2003 machine)
- On the WS2k3 machine we have a 3G broadband connection and installed a small proxy tool (analogx proxy) so that we could have internet access on the other computers.
- Also on the WS2k3 we have a software CISCO VPN tool enabled to access the company's intranet services.

The issues are essentially three:

1. The proxy tool only allows HTTP access and some internal services require access through different ports
2. The name resolution is hellish. It works whenever it feels like working (not reliable). I guess this has to do with the fact we're not connected to the domain server, but is there any easy way to make the wS2k3 machine mirror it?
3. IP resolution is also weak. It's not really as unreliable as name resolution, but at least it's very slow to connect.

What do you recommend as best approach to improve our small network?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dump the 3G and get ADSL, or go wireless (not 3G as data is too expensive and it's fairly slow).

Comment: @matt, the question said "field project", so wlan/adsl might not be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would:

1. Set up your "field" server as a RRAS server and demand-dial a VPN connection to the main office (assuming that your main office supports one of the Microsoft VPN types, such as PPTP) [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458975%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
2. Set up routing so that only traffic destined for the main office is routed through the afforementioned VPN link
3. This would ensure all other traffic is routed straight to the Internet
4. Your workstations would need to use the "field servers" IP address as their gateway

You don't really need a proxy for this, although it might save you a bit of bandwith in some cases.

The router config is actually easier to implement in many routers than in Windows because of the somewhat confusing RRAS console, but it should be fully possible. We used to run a similar config for a temp branch office back in the day.

As for name resolution, it's hard to say what's causing it. I would set up a local caching-only DNS. You can use conditional forwarders to send DNS requests for the main site's hostnames to the main internal DNS server, and regular "internet" requests to the 3G modems ISP's DNS server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment - some of it is somewhat cryptic to me, but I think I can manage to try out your suggestions and get back with  some further comments